# How could I remove this little gap between an image and header?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have `<a>` element with `<img>` and `<p>` inside my `<div>` element in here. And for some reason a small gap occurs between an image and the text that I can't remove. I tried adding `margin-top: 0px` to the `<p>` element, but it didn't fix the issue. Is there any other way I could remove this gap?

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Here is the screenshot:]

And here the html and css:

```css
.project-tile {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.project-tile:hover .brackets{
    color: orange;
}

.project_screenshot {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.project_name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-tile" id="tribute_page">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/full/PooYQbG" target="_blank" id="tribute_page_link">
            <img class="project_screenshot" src="https://i.imgur.com/cV4pKsg.png" alt="tribute_page_screenshot">
            <p class="project_name"><span class="brackets">&lt;</span> Tribute Page <span class="brackets">/&gt</span></p>
          </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default vertical alignment set to `baseline`.

Just add `display:block` or `vertical-align:top` to the image. With your class, that would apply to `.project_screenshot`